# How to insert values from dataframe to delta table

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a delta table where I'm storing all the data from dataframe in databricks.
Consider I have 5 columns in delta table A,B,C,D,E

If my dataframe has 4 columns (A,B,C,D) I need to insert all those 4 columns to delta table and last column(E) as null. and if I have 6 columns(A,B,C,D,E,F) in dataframe it should create one extra column(F) in delta table and insert it.

How to achieve this scenario using pyspark? Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use schema evolution in writing the DataFrame. every time new columns come from the source data, spark will add new columns in the target schema, remembering that this is a very expensive operation.

```py
df.write.format("delta") \
           .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
           .mode("append") \
           .save(local_path)
```